# Using the flattened array syntax in C++, crashes depending on width/height

Tags: c++, arrays, flatten

I have read quite a few articles in SO and cplusplus.com and decided to give a try to the flattened, 1D array that mimics 2D and 3D.
I managed to get a prototype to work with some values, but there is something wrong with the indices, which has to be the formula. All I did was copy the formula from different places and applied to the code. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
float *flat_2d_array, *flat_3d_array;
int width, height, depth, counter;

counter = 1;
width = 2;
height = 3;
depth = 4;
flat_2d_array = new float[width * height];
flat_3d_array = new float[width * height * depth];

// 2D part, works fine
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        flat_2d_array[y * width + x] = counter++;

for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        cout << "Element [" << x << "]" << "[" << y << "] = " << flat_2d_array[y * width + x] << endl;

cout << endl;
// Resets the counter and runs the 3D part
counter = 1;
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for(int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
            flat_3d_array[z * height * depth + y * depth + x] = counter++;

for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for(int z = 0; z < depth; z++)
            cout << "Element [" << x << "]" << "[" << y << "]" << "[" << z << "] = " << flat_3d_array[z * height * depth + y * depth + x] << endl;

delete[] flat_2d_array;
delete[] flat_3d_array;

return 0;
}
```

It just declares a few variables, allocates memory for the arrays, populates them with a counter in for() loops and prints the elements, then frees the memory.

If you copy/paste it will compile the way it is and will run fine.
However, if you change width to 3 and height to 2, then compile and run, it will crash after the element [2][1][3] in the 3D part.
So there seems to be indexing problem with this formula I'm using for the 3D:

```
3d_array[ X ][ Y ][ Z ] == flat_3d_array[ Z * height * depth + Y * depth + X ]
```

Can you guys see anything incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you guys see anything incorrect?

yes, your formula should be instead:

```
z * height * width + y * width + x
```

or more efficient form:

```
( z * height  + y ) * width + x
```

and you should make loop on `x` inner, otherwise you iterate against CPU cache.

To make clear: making loop on `x` inner would not affect correctness of your program, it will make it more efficient (including iteration on 2d array as well). Your program crashes because you calculate linear index for 3d array by wrong formula.

Comment: Thanks. You say I should swap the x and z loops? Wow, I'm surprised these suggestions are taken for granted to work and are pretty much everywhere. You make the dimensions different, the thing breaks.

Comment: If you make loop on `x` inner (not changing anything else) you do not make the dimensions different, what are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation again, Slava. The rant I made above was not to you, but about code that is found around and taken for granted to work, but as soon as a few parameters are changed, it stops working. What I asked about your comment on the x loop is about the optimal order: for(y) for(z) for(x), or for(z) for(y) for(x), as in both cases x is inner.

Comment: Optimal would be to use one loop with one index instead of 3 and you better use `std::vector` for that. So loop would be `for( auto &f : flat_2d_array) f = counter++;` or even better `std::iota( flat_2d_array.begin(), flat_2d_array.end(), 1 );`

Comment: I have to thank you again for further clarifying. Let me mark your answer as the solution as it fixed the issue.